# leave a new line only before a pattern

Tags: perl, shell, sed

i need to reformat a file in shell, so i only leave the 'new line' before some pattern. Ex:

Input:

```
Europe First
Asia Second
Africa Third
Australia Fourth
Europe Sixth
Australia Seventh
Europe  Eight
America Last
```

Output:

```
Europe FirstAsia SecondAfrica ThirdAustralia Fourth
Europe SixthAustralia Seventh
Europe  EightAmerica Last
```

where the pattern is "Europe"

Comment: Is this homework? If so it should be tagged as such

Comment: Is there raelly a blank line between every line? I'm gusessing there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -0777pe's/\n(?!Europe|\z)/ /g' file
```

Comment: Thx. By the quickness of the response i understand this must be very simple thing to do. Being new to Perl i am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: The options (`-i`, `-0`, `-p` and `-e`) are documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: Oops, I thought I was suppose to add spaces, but I misread. If you don't want the spaces, remove the space from the replacement expression.

Comment: As for the substitution operator, it's used to replace all newlines that aren't follows by `Europe` or the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `chomp` every line and `print` it, preceding it with an additional newline if it starts with the pattern

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print "\n"  if /^Europe/; print' myfile
```

Comment: I would use `perl -pe 'chomp; s/^/\n/ if /Europe/ && $.-1; END {print "\n"}'` to avoid blank line at the beginning and missing newline at the end.

Comment: Maybe. And ikegami chose to put spaces between the concatenated lines. But the requirement is so simple that I think any elaboration is probably superfluous

Comment: Why `$.-1` instead of `$. >1`?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nEurope/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```